# Is there a realtime, uncut video of Saturn V ignition through tower clear?

Tags: launch, nasa, apollo-program, saturn-v, video

"Hi, I'm Organic Marble and I'm bad at searching Youtube."

Inspired by this question [What event determined the transfer of control from Kennedy Space Center to Houston?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36211/6944), I'd like  to watch a 1:1 (realtime) video that shows a Saturn V launch from ignition until it passes the top of the tower, in one continuous shot.

All the ones I can find cut to different cameras to add visual interest.

I don't care about video quality so much, or what the rest of the video contains.

Does anyone have a link to such a video?

Comment: Looking at the clip in the answer, I started to think one of the reasons why there might be cuts in so many videos might be because the dynamic range necessary to go from sitting on the launch pad to the entire flame trail in view seems to have been beyond cameras of the time. Perhaps cutting to a camera that is not wildly overexposed after the flame becomes visible is one of the motivations for such cuts.

Comment: Agreed, right about the time the tower is cleared, it's so bright that it's hard to see exactly when it happens.

Comment: Hot-tip about YouTube searching: Log out of your YouTube account first (or use a browser you don't often use), the biases of personal preference YouTube (and Google) impose on you can make finding things harder. I miss 10 years ago when they didn't have that technology.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn thanks! With me, it's probably more that I am too impatient to watch internet videos, so I just have very little experience with Youtube.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When in doubt for such things, http://archive.org.

https://archive.org/details/youtube-Y70SgYPIBGY

Or if you prefer on YouTube